# Derivative of 1 + abs(x + 2)

Tags: derivatives, continuity, absolute-value

Given the equation $f(x)= 1 + |x + 2|$ in x = -2, I want to evaluate the limit in x = -2, and the derivative of the function to look for continuity,  and to check if its possible to get $f'$.

I don't know how to evaluate limits of abs, and then the derivative.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the left and right hand limit separately. Then the absolute value can be dropped, whence you can add the appropriate sign, and you can evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens when you approach $x = -2$ from both sides. From the right-hand side, $x > -2$, so we have $f(x) = 1 + x + 2$. Thus, the limit as we approach from the right is $f(-2) = 1$. From the left-hand side, $ x < -2$, so $f(x) = 1 - (x+2)$, and still $f(-2) = 1$. Since absolute value is continuous, you can conclude that the limit as $x$ approaches $-2$ of $f$ is $1$.

Now consider the derivative of $f$. When we approach $x = -2$ from the right, $f' = 1$, yet when we approach from the left, $f' = -1$. At the specific point $x = -2$, the derivative is thus undefined. (Everywhere else it is defined piecewise.)